# AngularJS orderBy does not work with track by in ngOptions?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to sort `ngOptions` with `track by`

This is my template

```
<select ng-model="asd" ng-options="user.id as user.name for user in users track by user.id | orderBy: 'name'">
```

This is my controller

```
function AppCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.users = [
   {id : 25, name: 'Batista'},
   {id : 26, name: 'Ultimate Warrior'},
   {id : 27, name: 'Andre the giant'}
  ];
  $scope.name = 'asdasd';
  $scope.asd = 25;
 }
```

I wrote a [snippet in JSBin](http://jsbin.com/kipoh/1/edit) to demonstrate this. The problem with this is the sorting does not work. Should I write a custom filter?

Answer (score 194, accepted):

In order to use tracking with filters, the `track by` expression needs to be added after the filter.

Try this instead:

```
user.id as user.name for user in users | orderBy: 'name' track by user.id
```

The documentation for [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) mentions this under the "Arguments" section, specifically:

> Filters should be applied to the expression, before specifying a tracking expression.

and

> For example: *item in items | filter:searchText track by item.id* is a pattern that might be used to apply a filter to items in conjunction with a tracking expression.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing this one out!  One question, how about when you want to use an order by function instead of a property?