# angularjs sortby for date unix timestamp not working

Tags: angularjs

i'm trying to order a json array using angularjs using timestamp, but its not working for somereson

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts track by post.id|orderBy:'post_date':reverse" class="list-group-item apost">
  <h4 class="timeline-title">{{post.title}}</h4>
</div>
```

js

```
$scope.Posts = [
  {"id":1,"user_id":1,"title":"Welcome to MRI","body":"\u0641\u064a \u062d\u0627\u0644\u0647 \u0627\u064a \u0627\u0633\u062a\u0641\u0627","post_date":1422929860,"fullname":"MZ"},
  {"id":3,"user_id":1,"title":"\u0641\u064a \u062d\u0627\u0644\u0647 \u0636\u0627,","post_date":1422933651,"fullname":"MZ"},
  {"id":24,"user_id":1,"title":"\u0641\u064a \u062d\u0627\u0644\u0647 \u0627\u064a \u0627\u0633\u062a\u0641\u0633\u0627\u0631","body":"\u0628\u0631\u0631","post_date":1425404937,"fullname":"Mz"},
  {"id":29,"user_id":1,"title":"new post","body":"fk shit mf","post_date":1425405333,"fullname":"MZ"}
]
```

i want to show newest posts first.

also is it possible to check if the post_date is today in angular template to apply a special class ?

Comment: This looks related to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23925482/651848.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23925482/651848), you have to use `track by` after your `orderBy` statement.

And from [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) documentation (see 'Arguments' table):

> For example: `item in items | filter:searchText track by item.id` is a
>   pattern that might be used to apply a filter to items in conjunction
>   with a tracking expression.

Based on this info I think you want to use something like:

```
post in posts | orderBy:'post_date':true track by post.id
```

---

> also is it possible to check if the post_date is today in angular
>   template to apply a special class ?

For this you could define a function to check if your value is today in  `$scope`.

Angular JS:

```
.controller("PostCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.isToday = function(date) {
       /**
        * Logic to determine if date is today or not goes here.
        * Will either return true or false.
        */
    };
})
```

Then within your HTML template, you can pass each post's date into `isToday`. If it returns true then your specialClass will get applied.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'post_date':true track by post.id" class="list-group-item apost">
  <h4 class="timeline-title" ng-class="{specialClass: isToday(post.post_date)}">{{post.title}}</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks that worked !. i also had to change :reverse to :true and that solved the problem :) angular 1.3

Comment: @Zalaboza I attempted to answer the second part of your question. Let me know if it's not clear to you.